# Word to denote one who is being harassed simply with an intent to harass another

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, for example, one wants to harass Tom so that he runs away from that place leaving behind his legacy. For that end, his kid is being harassed by society or anyone.

Is there any word that can be used for the kid like one can say the kid is being used as a 'xxx' or something like that?

Comment: *Sacrifical lamb*, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [scapegoat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scapegoat) - one that is the object of irrational hostility.

"The kids is a scapegoat for them."

Comment: Yes, fits my context. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **proxy**.

So if **Bill** (who hates Tom) harasses Tom's kid **Jane**, to get at **Tom**;
then we could say that,

- *Bill is harassing Tom by through the proxy of Jane.*
- *Jane is being used as a proxy target, to get at Tom*

It is harassment via **proxy**.
The proxy is the kid.

Comment: Yes, this one fits too my context. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ravi A proxy scapegoat.

Comment: Plz clarify one point. Though its clear that Tom is harassed via proxy, does your 1st bullet imply that the proxy Jane is also harassed? So 2nd bullet can be used by explicitly mentioning harassment as - `Jane is being used as a proxy target of harassment, to get at Tom.`

Comment: yes. consider an internet proxy, and a proxy war, and a proxy vote.